# C# TextBox to use Quotations to mean whole phrase

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

In a Web Forms project, I have a textbox on my page that when the user enters text it automatically strips the whitespace, adds a comma, and then pushes each word into an array. (i do a bit of string.Split, string.Replace and string.ToArray)

This functionality is what i need, however i need to perform another.

When a user enters words but surrounds them with quotation marks i need that to act as a single phrase.

So if a user enters `-red oak tree-` this is created as an array of 3 (red and oak and tree) but if a user enters `-"red oak tree"-` this is seen as the phrase "red oak tree"

I do use a checkbox to handle this at the moment but i need the check to be done if the words are in quotation marks, with no checkbox.

Comment: What if I need to include a phrase with a quotation mark?

Comment: Of That i am not 100% sure. For what my project does it needs the phrase to do a full text search on a sql backend, without a sub-phrase within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the first and last characters

```
string str = "red oak tree";
if (str.Length > 2 && str[0] == '\"' && str[str.Length - 1] == '\"') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I Threw this into my Visual Studio 2017 and was presented by compilation errors. on the str[0] == "\"" && str[str.Length - 1] == "\"". what i got was "operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

Comment: @ElishaSpicer alright I updated my answer. But just a tip, in the future you should really try to use google to search errors first because most of the time someone else has already found the answer

Comment: I had searched for it, and at the same time i was letting you know that the posted code was generating an error, But thank you for your help!